# How to write a post routing request which takes multiple links Sinatra

Tags: ruby, post, sinatra

I basically want to write a POST request in sinatra that has to take 3 links at the same time and process it in someway.

```
post account/:id/
```

Here id represents the user id...what will come after

```
:id/
```

so that I can capture 3 links like link1, link2, link3 and then do something with it inside the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this with interpolated path variables is very inflexible.  Rather do it by accepting a posted array of parameters

If you absolutely have to do this; the syntax is something like

```
post 'account/:id/link1/:link1/link2/:link2/link3/:link3'
```

Comment: Will this capture the links and how will I manipulate it inside the request?   what is the other way of doing it?

Comment: @gautam Like mcfinnigan says, use the params of the POST request, see [the POST route example at the end of the Streaming Responses section of the docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Streaming%20Responses) for an example of accessing the `params` object.